# How can I execute a php file with python and then parse the results?

Tags: python, php

How can I execute a php file with python and then parse the results?
In this case I want to loop through the array and show each date.

php file `dates.php`:

```php
<?php 
function dates()
{
   return ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-06'];
}
dates();
?>
```

This is my Python script (an example):

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['php', '/dates.php'], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
    check=True               
)
# returns nothing 
print(result.stdout)

# I want to loop through the array and show the results
for date in result.stdout:
   date # '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'..
```

Comment: you'll need PHP to echo the data, perhaps doing in JSON format would make sense then python can read the text from stdout and parse it. They're two separate programs / processes, so treat the interaction like you would anything like that (including if you were doing this over HTTP) - define an interface and data interchange format, and use it. JSON would be ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Once I was mixing python, bash and PowerShell. I was using 2 files for all the data input/output, so a file might be a solution for you too :)

Comment: This should be a comment at best, and even then I'm not sure how it would be helpful.

Comment: You need to use Python's built-in os library via 'import os' and then something like myOutput = os.system("php myPhpScript.php") to get the results. Although if you post the code you tried, you are more likely to get a solution on stackoverflow.